# Can you create multiple instances dynamically of a docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to know if there is any way to dynamically run multiple instances of the same docker-compose.

That is, to add a new instance you do not have to stop or restart the others that are already running. Nor is it known in advance how many instances are to be needed.

Obviously the exposed ports would be different in each instance, for example in the following configuration file exposes an ephemeral port:

```yaml
version: '3'
  services:
    nginx:
      image: nginx:latest
      volumes:
        - /home/USER/nginx-configuration:/etc/nginx
      ports:
        - 80
```

What I found is the `--scale` parameter according to the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/scale/), but it does not allow it to be done dynamically.

Comment: I think you need to try docker swarm instead for your purpose where you can scale up and/or scale down the instances of your services.

Comment: You could launch multiple copies of an entire Compose file, if you set [`$COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) separately for each one, made sure to not specify fixed names like `container_name:`, and took care around bind-mounted files and port mappings; but you can't readily launch multiple identical copies of single services (without Swarm or another more complex tool).

Comment: @GauravAgarwal is it possible to create more than one instance of a stack in docker swarm with different configurations (for instancethe port) ?

Comment: @itasahobby I don't know if that is possible. Though you could make the same image with the same Dockerfile (but different image name) and give a different port to it's container.